# How to implement jQuery's load() function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making an async call from a webpage to another resource at a url like `/example/url/here.html` which contains a partial view and inserting the response into the `innerHTML` of a div on the first page. However, the partial view here.html might contain `<script>` references and some inline script that doesn't get loaded/run when inserting to innerHTML.

I'm wondering if jQuery's load() function would solve this, and if so how to implement a similar function in javascript, as I cannot use jQuery.

Here's the code I'm using that isn't working:

```
     function (elemId, url) {

        var successCallback = function (responseText) {
            var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
            elem.innerHTML(responseText);
        };

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                successCallback(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

Comment: You need to do what jQuery does: parse the `responseText` and look for `<script>` elements. It extracts them and creates new `<script>` nodes with the content.

Comment: So if I create new <script> nodes it will load/execute them?

Comment: Take the jQuery source code for the function, after all, jQuery is just Javascript.

Comment: @Nit The code for this is buried deep inside the `.html()` code, it's not in `.load()` itself.

Comment: @Zack Yes. You can also use `eval()` to execute the code.

Comment: just set the script tag `src` to the url to the file and append it to the page

Comment: So the issue is that the file isn't just javascript. it's html that also has javascript in it. However, the javascript in the page isn't being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is load the html partial via jquery like this:

```
<div id="partial" ></div>

$('#partial').load('somefile.html');
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to figure out is how to implement that without jQuery.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/53aa87f3bf4284763405f3eb8affff296e55ba4f/src/ajax/load.js